# How to load single COM instance for multiple application instance

Tags: vba, com

I'm creating a COM dll and it will be loaded by VBA. However, I noticed that for every excel instance (workbook), a new COM object is loading to memory. But I need to maintain single COM state irrespective of number of Excel instances exists.

Please help me achieve this purpose .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

> [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html)